# How do I add custom options to an export script (like triangulate faces, unwrap UVs, etc.)?

Tags: python, scripting, export

I have a functioning export script that I haven't worked on since about a year ago. I'm just getting back into polishing it up and optimizing the code, but I can't remember how to add check boxes, custom values, and such in the UI export panel. I googled for some templates and tutorials, but I couldn't find anything.

Any example code that someone can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add user adjustable options you add [properties](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#operator-example) to your export operator.

If you want to customize the way the options are displayed, add a `draw(self, context)` to your operator, which works the same as a [panel draw method](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#example-panel).

```
import bpy

class ExportData(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Export objects to file"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.data"
    bl_label = "Export data"

    do_triangulate = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
            name="Triangulate faces",
            description="Triangulate all faces.",
            default=True,
            )

    sample_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
            name="example",
            description="Just an example.",
            min=0.0, max=1000.0,
            soft_min=0.0, soft_max=100.0,
            default=0.0,
            )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, "do_triangulate")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, "sample_float", expand=True)

    def execute(self, context):
        # do your exporting here
```

You can find examples of how this works in most of the import/export scripts included with blender such as the [obj exporter](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/__init__.py)